# Excel doesn't accept formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Another SU thread, [How do I change whole number into a decimal number in Excel?](https://superuser.com/q/927003/364367), deals with the problem of taking a multi-digit whole number and inserting a decimal point between the first and second digits.  I tried one of the solutions posted there, but Excel 2019 is telling me that there is a problem with this formula:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,1)&"."&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

I can't see a reason why the formula would work for others but not for me.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post and add sample data, also the expected out put,, since the attached link itself is a solutions !!

Answer (score 2):

Your formula works fine for me. Do your regional settings use a decimal point? Then the formula will work for a cell value that has only numeric digits and nothing else.

If your regional settings use a comma as the decimal separator, you probably also need semicolons instead of commas in the formula.

This formula will work in the typical European settings with decimal comma and semicolon as the list separator.

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1;1)&","&RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-1))
```

This formula will work in the US settings with decimal point and comma as the list separator

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A1,1)&"."&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))
```

Comment: thank you, it worked with semicolon as the list separator.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If this solved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour].